# Removing last part of string divided by a colon

Tags: php, string

I have a string that looks a little like this, `world:region:bash`

It divides folder names, so i can create a path for FTP functions.

However, i need at some points to be able to remove the last part of the string, so, for example

I have this `world:region:bash`

I need to get this `world:region`

The script wont be able to know what the folder names are, so some how it needs to be able to remove the string after the last colon.

Comment: `<?php str_replace(':bash','');  ?>`

Comment: [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: @RPM "The script wont be able to know what the folder names are, so some how it needs to be able to remove the string after the last colon."

Comment: it sounds like a reg ex can solve this'

Comment: Have a look at the Related column to the right - there are many pointers to what you want.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$res=substr($input,0,strrpos($input,':'));
```

I should probably highlight that strrpos not strpos finds last occurrence of a substring in given string

Comment: this would only return the string up to the first colon

Comment: my bad, `strrpos` looks like `strpos`

Comment: IMHO should exist a check to strpos, in case if there's no colon in the string, otherwise throw an error due substr is expecting int not boolean. Anyway, can be done just placing a cast ```$res=substr($input,0,(int)strrpos($input,':'));```

Comment: As @G-Nugget said in a comment before, we only get the the string to the first coolon. What I did to solve this is a while to check if we still have some trimming to do using strpos(), when it's done we will exit the loop and problem solved

Answer (score 6):

```
$tokens = explode(':', $string);      // split string on :
array_pop($tokens);                   // get rid of last element
$newString = implode(':', $tokens);   // wrap back
```

Comment: Using this, it give me Arrayworld:region

Comment: You can replace the first two lines with `$tokens = explode(':', $string, -1);`

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try something like this:

```
<?php
  $variable = "world:region:bash";
  $colpos = strrpos($variable, ":");
  $result = substr($variable, 0, $colpos);
  echo $result;
?>
```

Or... if you create a function using this information, you get this:

```
<?php
  function StrRemoveLastPart($string, $delimiter)
  {
    $lastdelpos = strrpos($string, $delimiter);
    $result = substr($string, 0, $lastdelpos);
    return $result;
  }

  $variable = "world:region:bash";
  $result = StrRemoveLastPart($variable, ":");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Explode the string, and remove the last element.
If you need the string again, use implode.

```
$items = array_pop(explode(':', $the_path));
$shotpath = implode(':', $items);
```

Comment: Good idea, however, the array could be very long, is there an function like array_length or something?

Comment: count gives the array length. However, you not need it to remove the last item.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression `/:[^:]+$/`, [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$s = "world:region:bash";
$p = "/:[^:]+$/";
$r = '';

echo preg_replace($p, $r, $s);
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/ybz3r)

Notice how `$` which means string termination, is made use of.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$string = 'world:region:bash';
$string = implode(':', explode(':', $string, -1));
```