# How do I remove the colon form the start of the variable in Slim PHP?

Tags: php, slim

I am parsing through multiple variables like it says in the [Slim Framework Documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Parameters) using the following route:

```
$app->get('/admin-edit-module/:stackid/:envid/:id'
```

This parses through the values, but there is also a '`:`' before each of the values.

The output when I print the variables are:

```
:1:2:32
```

I want it to output 1 2 32

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334614/removing-last-part-of-string-divided-by-a-colon) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple fix. This for each of the variables:

```
$stackid = str_replace(":", "", $stackid);
```

Wasn't sure if there was another way round it using the Slim Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into `explode()`?

```
<?php

$stackids = ':1:2:32';

$stackids = explode(":", $stackids);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($stackids, true).'</pre>';

foreach($stackids as $key=>$value){
    echo $value'<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: I saw it on other posts, my solution below seems to be a quicker fix / less code. Cheers though!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. I just wasn't sure if you needed to do something different with each value. Cheers!